# How to build react-native minified "prod" app for simulator?

Tags: ios, react-native

How can I run a react-native app in *production* mode on the simulator? I figured out how to generate the minified bundle...

```
$ react-native bundle --minify
Building package...
transforming [========================================] 100% 302/302
Build complete
Successfully saved bundle to ios/main.jsbundle
```

... but I don't understand how to load `ios/main.jsbundle` into the simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using the below. Xcode is loading from not iOS/main.jsbundle but iOS/PROJ/main.jsbundle.. It could be only my case because I've been upgraded react-native version a couple of times.

```
$ react-native bundle --out iOS/MyProj/main.jsbundle --minify
```

Regarding prod, use `?dev=false`. Also making sure to build as "Release" scheme.

```
// AppDelegate.m
jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?dev=false"];
```